# I have an problem with my AI Trainer that i got from youtube: "TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments."

Tags: python

So, i want to use an ai trainer i got from a guy from youtube, and i have an problem when i am running it. The problem doesn't seem to go away when i change the mediapipe version.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\intresting\aitrainer.py", line 8, in <module>
    detector = pm.poseDetector()
  File "E:\intresting\PoseModule.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.upBody, self.smooth,
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\pose.py", line 146, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 274, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 275, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 533, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
```

This is the error, can you please help me?

Comment: Post your code, can't diagnose the problem without seeing what's happening.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that a boolean value can only be 1 or 0, not 0.5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.